# extract application layer header from pcap file in string mode

Tags: c#, pcap

I have a PCAP file that contains packet data with payload.

I want to extract application layer header from this file in ASCII format.

A sample for HTTP header is like this:

```
GET /chatroom_4.jpg HTTP/1.1
Full request URI: http://patogh.khalezanak.com/img/ui/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
LOCATION: http://172.18.39.154:51202
GET /img/ui/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
HTTP/1.1 200 Log Processed
```

How can I do it with `sharppcap` or `pcap.net` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use Justniffer. One example is here: https://seguridadyredes.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/justniffer-un-sniffer-que-reensambla-reordena-y-muestras-los-flujos-tcp/

It is highly customizable:

```
justniffer -f ../pcap1/http.pcap -l "%request.header.grep([^\s]*[\s]*([^\s]*)) %response.header.grep(Content-Type:(\s)*([^\r]*)) %source.ip"
```

Best Regards,